# Matching against multiple Boxed values

Tags: rust, match, move-semantics

I have the following code which compiles fine

```
#[derive(Debug, PartialEq, Clone)]
pub enum Expression {
    Const(i32),
    Neg(Box<Expression>),
    Add(Box<Expression>, Box<Expression>),
}

fn simplify(expr: &Expression) -> Expression {
    match expr {
        Expression::Neg(x) => match **x {
            Expression::Const(n) => Expression::Const(-n),
            _ => expr.clone() 
        },  

        // GIVES ERROR
        // Expression::Add(x, y) => match (**x, **y) {
        //     (Expression::Const(n), Expression::Const(m)) => Expression::Const(n + m),
        //     _ => expr.clone() 
        // },
    
    
        Expression::Add(x, y) => match **x {
            Expression::Const(n) => match **y {
                Expression::Const(m) => Expression::Const(n + m), 
                _ => expr.clone() 
            }   
            _ => expr.clone() 
        }   


        _ => expr.clone() 
    }   
}
```

But if I replace the `Expression::Add` arm with the commented out version, I get the following compiler error

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of `**x` which is behind a shared reference
  --> src/lib.rs:21:41
   |
21 |         Expression::Add(x, y) => match (**x, **y) {
   |                                         ^^^ move occurs because `**x` has type `Expression`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait

error[E0507]: cannot move out of `**y` which is behind a shared reference
  --> src/lib.rs:21:46
   |
21 |         Expression::Add(x, y) => match (**x, **y) {
   |                                              ^^^ move occurs because `**y` has type `Expression`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0507`.
```

Is there a reason we may match against the lone `**x` but not in a tuple like `(**x, **y)`?  Is the former actually being converted or hiding some syntactic sugar?  Is there a simpler way of writing this `Add` arm than with the two nested matches?

EDIT:  I also see that there is a `ref` keyword, which is [supposed to address](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/keyword.ref.html) something like this, but changing my tuple match expression to `(ref **x, ref **y)` gives a syntax error (`error: expected expression, found keyword ref`).

Comment: I'm not sure what's going on, but `match (&**x, &**y)` works. (And `ref` goes on to variable declarations in the match arms. You're using it in the wrong place, syntactically.)

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR:** Match against `(&**x, &**y)`.

---

What's going on here is interesting. And the TL;DR is: **when you `match v {}`, you don't read `v`. You create a *place* for `v`.**

A *place* is something we can read from. Or write to. Or do nothing with. The important point is that creating place alone does not involve such operation. You can read/write it later, but when you create it, it is just a place.

In your `match`, the type of `x` and `y` is `&Box<Expression>`. When we `match **x`, *we don't read `x`*. Thus, we don't move `**x` either. What we do is create a place for `**x`. We then match this place against `Expression::Const(n)`. Now we read `x` and extract `n` out of it. But `n` is `i32` - `Copy` - so this is fine.

In contrast, when you use a tuple `(**x, **y)`, since you don't match against `**x` and `**y` directly you do read them. And because you read them, and they are not `Copy` (`Expression`), you move out of them. Now this is an error because you cannot move out of shared references. You match them *after*, but they've already moved.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `match(x.as_ref(),y.as_ref())`